# Mongodb no detecta si el campo_id existe

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

//En mi bd tengo un campo de usuarios el cual almacema un `ObjetId` unico de cada usuario pero al parecer mongo no esta reconociendo si el dato ya existe o no e igual lo esta guardando, no se bien cual seria el problema pero a mi parecer estoy ingresando mal los datos, les dejo mi codigo

```
usuarios: [{
   type: Schema.Types.ObjetId,
   ref: 'usuarios',
   unique: true
 }]
```

//ese es mi campo, usuario, acontinuacion dejare mi logica para ingresar ese dato:

```
public async insertUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const { _id } = req.body
   const user: any = await Usuario.findById(req.userId)
   user.usuarios.push(_id)
   let data = await user.save()
   if (data) {
       return res.status(200).json({message: 'ok.'})
   }else{
    return res.json({message: 'Intentelo de nuevo mas tarde.'})
   }
}
```

//Estoy ingresando ese id con un simple `.push(_id)`, no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, si necesitan mas informacion con gusto se las dare, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que usas el método [`push()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-push) del tipo [`Array`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Array) de Mongoose. El cual no valida si el elemento a ser agregado ya existe en la lista.

**SOLUCIÓN**

**1. Usando `addToSet()`:**

Puedes usar el método [`addToSet()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-addToSet), que no trata la colección como un `Array` sino que la trata como un Conjunto o `Set`.

El elemento a ser agregado a la colección será primero validado, si no existe, se agregará, si existe no se agregará.

Por ejemplo:

```js
public async insertUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const { _id } = req.body;
  const user: any = await Usuario.findById(req.userId);
  user.usuarios.addToSet(_id); // <- Se agregará sólo si no existe en la lista
  let data = await user.save();
  if (data) {
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'ok.'});
  } else {
    return res.json({message: 'Inténtelo de nuevo mas tarde.'});
  }
}
```

Si tienes varios elementos a ser añadidos, puedes usar el [operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator) de Javascript:

```js
public async insertUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const ids = [ /* Lista de ids */];
  const user: any = await Usuario.findById(req.userId);
  user.usuarios.addToSet(...ids); // <- Spread Operator
  let data = await user.save();
  if (data) {
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'ok.'});
  } else {
    return res.json({message: 'Inténtelo de nuevo mas tarde.'});
  }
}
```

**2. Usando una mezcla de `includes()` y `push()`:**

Los tipo `Array` de Mongoose incluyen varios métodos, ya conoces `push()` y `addToSet()`, ahora introducimos [`includes()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-includes).

La idea es verificar si el elemento a ser introducido en la lista ya existe. Para ello usamos el método `includes()` que nos devolverá un booleano cuyo valor será `true` si el elemento que estamos chequeando existe en la lista o `false` en caso contrario.

Por ejemplo:

```js
public async insertUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const { _id } = req.body;
  const user: any = await Usuario.findById(req.userId);
  if(!user.usuarios.includes(_id)) { // Si no existe el _id en la lista
    // es seguro usar push aquí, ya que hemos verificado con includes
    user.usuarios.push(_id); // <- Se agregará sólo si no existe en la lista
  }
  let data = await user.save();
  if (data) {
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'ok.'});
  } else {
    return res.json({message: 'Inténtelo de nuevo mas tarde.'});
  }
}
```

Si tuvieras un `Array` de `_id`'s para incluir en tu lista, se puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```js
public async insertUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const ids = [ /* Lista de ids */];
  const user: any = await Usuario.findById(req.userId);
  // recorremos la lista de id's
  ids.forEach(id => {
    // solo se agregan los ids que no están repetidos
    if(!user.usuarios.includes(id)) {
      user.usuarios.push(id);
    }  
  });
  let data = await user.save();
  if (data) {
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'ok.'});
  } else {
    return res.json({message: 'Inténtelo de nuevo mas tarde.'});
  }
}
```

Con esto puedes resolver el problema.

---

**¿Porqué la restricción sobre el elemento marcado como `unique` no funciona al usar `push()`?**

Porque en MongoDB no existe (aún) el concepto de [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set) o Conjunto de Datos únicos. Sólo existe el tipo `Array`. Es por ello que la restricción que colocas sobre tu documento no tiene ningún tipo de efecto al momento de usar `push()`.